# rxjs6 'share()' does not work with 'of(...)'?

Tags: rxjs6

Why observable created with `of(...)` does not share source among multiple subscribers? `timer(...)` and `Observable.create(...)` work as expected. I couldn't find any mention of it in the documentation.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cygjdt?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but it's synchronous so in your example:

```
// of
const ofSource = of('hi');
const ofExample = ofSource.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('***SIDE EFFECT - OF***'))
);

const ofSharedExample = ofExample.pipe(share());

ofSharedExample.subscribe(() => console.log('of sub 1'));
ofSharedExample.subscribe(() => console.log('of sub 2'));
```

The first subscription is completed before the second is subscribed. So `share` will unsubscribe the underlying observable because there are no other subscribers to *share* the observable with.

If however you add `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` (or some other async behavior) you will 'delay' the subscriptions and get a shared `of`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xcwyew?file=index.ts